# Facebook Credits: Obtaining the number of credits

Tags: facebook, facebook-credits

Just wanted to know if anyone knows how to query the Facebook Credits (FBC) API for the number of credits a user has?  My application has this requirement, and there's is no explanation or mention of this in the FBC API.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

It seems that this was something missing from the Facebook Credits API.

This is a feature that seems to be avialable only to developers that are using Facebook Credits as the exclusive method of payment.

More info @ http://developers.facebook.com/docs/creditsapi , section "**Get Balance**".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try checkout Facebook's Credits API @ http://developers.facebook.com/docs/creditsapi?

Answer (score 0):

I searched before, but there is no method to get user credits, no Graph API or FQL Tables can return user credits.

Comment: You reckon this is still the case?

Answer (score 0):

There is no longer a "Get Balance" section on that page and no other information there to says how to get the user's credit balance.